# How to change a string like "$123.4" into floatValue

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsscanner

Just like the title : how can i change a string @"$123.4" into a float value 123.4 in iOS

```
NSString *string = @"$123.4";
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Giki

Comment: `float price = [[string substringFromIndex:1] floatValue];`. Also, why the `NSScanner` tag?

Comment: Alternative for memory management freaks: `float price = strtof(string.UTF8String + 1, NULL);`

Answer (score 3):

@H2CO3 smart answer but i tried this last.

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
formatter.currencyCode = @"USD";    
float value = [[formatter numberFromString: @"$123.45"] floatValue];

NSLog(@"%f",value);
```

Comment: this works good, but @user2277872 trick will fail if there is space or something in index 0 
( e.g.      NSString *string = @" $123.4";) 
so +1 to you bit-whacker

Comment: @SuryakantSharma Correct, 1 white Space can change the result.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma, I wasn't giving the answer, I was relaying the answer from the comment under the question because it seemed to be a good answer.

Comment: ok @user2277872 I wasn't saying you are wrong but that line of code seems failing for some cases that's what I just pointed out.
So cheers man.

Comment: oh, no i understand what you're saying :) i Just wanted to make sure you didn't think I wrote it cuz i had the link for @H2C03 on it.

Comment: @user2277872 as i also mentioned that Good Idea, and my point everyone here bcoz of learn something new as i learned from your answered so and you also good as you gave final touch. so good luck.

Comment: guys. You're so awesome. Thanks for all your solutions.\n and i tried this:NSString *string = @"￥123.4";
    NSString *newString = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"floatString:%.1f",newString.floatValue);

Comment: @Giki nice but what if `NSString *string = @" ￥123.4";` white space before `￥` ?

Answer (score 1):

As seen with @H2C03

```
float price = [[string substringFromIndex:1] floatValue];
```

Hope this helps!